# Converting byte array to pdf throws error when opening the dcoument

Tags: c#, wcf, pdf, bytestream

I am developing a WCF service that downloads a pdf file from a internet portal converts it into byte array and sends it to the client. On client side i am converting this byte array to pdf by using WriteAllBytes method. But while opening the pdf document it displays "There is error while opening the documnet. The file might be damaged or corrupted"

**WCF Code**
//

```
FileInformation fileInfo = File.OpenBinaryDirect(clientContext, fileRef.ToString());

 byte[] Bytes = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fileSize)]; 
fileInfo.Stream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length); 
return Bytes;
```

**Client code**

```
byte[] recievedBytes = <call to wcf method returing byte array>;
                File.WriteAllBytes(path, recievedBytes);
```

Comment: Well have you compared the original document with the downloaded version, e.g. in terms of size and some hash? We could really do with seeing your code... currently we have no clue as to where the problem might be.

Comment: No, please put the information *in the question*. (It's not even clear whether that code was your client code or the WCF code, to be honest...) You also didn't answer any my question about comparisons you'd performed between the files.

Comment: Yes, i compared the documents. There seems to be no difference.

Comment: *How* did you compare them? Just size, or hash as well? Note that calling `Stream.Read` and ignoring the result is almost always a bad idea - you would normally want to keep looping until all the bytes have been read, using the return value of the `Read` call to see how many bytes were actually read in each call.

Comment: I compared the size.

Comment: Right. So if you'd written just the first chunk of bytes correctly, but then not the rest, that would explain everything.

Comment: I jus checked the Stream.read by storing the bytes read in a variable. During debugging i found out that it just read a meagre 3145 bytes whereas the file size is 100875 bytes. how is that?

Comment: That's entirely reasonable for `Stream.Read` - it isn't guaranteed to read all the data in one chunk.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect this is the problem:

```
byte[] Bytes = new byte[Convert.ToInt32(fileSize)]; 
fileInfo.Stream.Read(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length);
```

You're assuming a single call to `Read` will read *everything*. Instead, you should loop round until you *have* read everything. For example:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) fileSize];
int index = 0;
while (index < bytes.Length)
{
    int bytesRead = fileInfo.Stream.Read(bytes, index, bytes.Length - index);
    if (bytesRead == 0)
    {
        throw new IOException("Unable to read whole file");
    }
    index += bytesRead;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream((int) fileSize];
fileInfo.Stream.CopyTo(output);
return output.ToArray();
```